# How do I wait in onBeforeAction for the user to be recognized?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I am logged into my website with accounts-facebook. When I load a page, onBeforeAction is called, and Meteor.user() is undefined. It loads the login template, and I see it briefly. Then onBeforeAction is re-run, and Meteor.user() is an object, and a different template is loaded. How do I either:

- wait in onBeforeAction until the user is recognized
- have onBeforeAction called after the user is recognized

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `fast-render` package. It makes `Meteor.user()` to be populated from the start. Simply run:

```
mrt add fast-render
```

Check out [this detailed article](http://meteorhacks.com/instant-login-for-meteor-with-fast-render.html) on how it works.